# Shortcode in wordpress printing always on the top with inline HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode inside a plugin I wrote. The shortcode always prints on top, after a bit of research I found that I have to 'return' instead of 'echo' for me to get it in the right place.

I have inline HTML , css , javascript in various script tags inside the PHP file. Is there a way I can get it work without trying to return all the inline HTML. (adding 'return' to all html tags is a huge endeavour) ?

I know that a question on shortcode printing on top has been asked but this is not entirely the same problem I am having.

Appreciate your answers.

Just for people to get an idea of the code I am dealing with: This is just a small chunk of the code, but there is html, css spread all over the place.

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id'=>'0', 'key'=>'0'), $atts));


if(substr($id, -3) == "***") $id = substr($id, 0, 8);
$id_licenses = getDbInfo($id);

$id_desc = array();
if(is_array($id_licenses)) $id_desc = $id_licenses;
else $id_desc[0] = $id_licenses;

if(isset($_POST['desc'])) {     
    $info = $_POST['desc'];

    $ids = getDbInfoByDesc($info);
}




?>

<style type="text/css">
label.inputlabel
{
width: 8em;
float: left;
text-align: left;
margin-right: 0.5em;
display: block; 
padding-left: 0.5em;

font-family: Tahoma;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return the final result but if you want you can buffer the result and `echo` anything inside the buffer then can retun the buffered data, i.e.

```
function yourShortCodeFunction(){
    ob_start();
    echo "Hello"; // this will not print out
    // more code
    $result = ob_get_contents(); // get everything in to $result variable
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: how do you deal with the inline HTML, css, javascript.
that is not in the php code, it is outside the php tags in the same file. ?
I think HTML gets output first.

Comment: Awesome, I tried it. Thanks. I was not aware that inline HTML not in the php tags would be considered as php strings.
I thought storing it in buffer would always be for echoed strings.